# Is there any statistic about how much reputation is created hourly in SO?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

I'm just curious if there is such a statistic available anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the query, you could use the [Query site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

You could sum the number of upvotes and group that by hour. That would give a rough image of the reputation given.

A good statistic would then create a different list of if it's a question or an answer being upvoted and multiply the number by the reputation it gives, and then look at the downvotes and reduce the number by those results.

Here's a naive query. You could take those results and plot them.

```
SELECT YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate), DAY(CreationDate), COUNT(Id) 
FROM VOTES 
GROUP BY​ YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate), DAY(CreationDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(CreationDate), MONTH(CreationDate), DAY(CreationDate)​
```

I ran it and charted it for you, just if you were curious.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXb3T.png

Warning, big png image.